# JPG (Binary data) download as AJAX response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I have a page where a user can download an image in the format he ask, the request is sent to a PHP script that produce the image and ... I want to serve to the user.
This is the JQUERY code sourced here on StackOverflow

```
                    $('[name ="download_img_ajax"]').click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault()
                        var element = this
                        var formdata = new FormData(element.closest(".form_downIMG"))
                        formdata.append('download_img_ajax','true')
                        $(this).next("span.down_response").html('Preparazione file in corso...'),
                        $('.emailadr').hide(),
                          $.ajax({
                               type: 'POST',
                               url: '$target_post',
                               data:  formdata,
                               cache: false,
                               contentType: false,
                               processData: false,
                            success: function(tornato) {
                              const blob = new Blob([tornato], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
                              const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                              const a = document.createElement("a");
                              a.href = downloadUrl;
                              a.download = "file.jpg";
                              document.body.appendChild(a);
                              a.click();
                              },
                        })
                      })
```

The PHP script generate the file as a tmp file ($img), but I don't understand how return it as a correct AJAX response.

`echo fread($img,filesize($img_path));`

isn't working (the file isn't recognized as JPG file) even if the size is correct.

In a normal form I return the file this way:

```
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');  // For Gecko browsers mainly
      header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');  // For download resume
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($img_path));  // File size
      header('Content-Encoding: none');
      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');  // Change this mime type if the file is not PDF
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $imgID);  // Make the browser display the Save As dialog
      readfile($img_path);
    fclose($img);
```

PS: In JQ I use next, closest, etc. because I have many forms in the same dynamically generated by PHP.

I will use this kind of download only for file of ~700KB, leaving the bigger file on the old method of a submit form with target="_blank" and readfile in the PHP. Is safe?

If I want manage also error (example the PHP script can't serve the file) how I can handle it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with FileSaver.js ( https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js )

```
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
                            xhr.open('POST', '$target_post')
                            xhr.responseType = 'blob'
                            xhr.onload = function() {
                              saveAs(xhr.response, 'immagine.jpg');
                            }
                            xhr.send(formdata)
```

the PHP
`echo fread($img,filesize($img_path));`